# popcorn.js play() Does Not Work for Vimeo Videos

Tags: vimeo, popcornjs

I'm using popcorn.js with Vimeo. I would like to play my Vimeo video programmatically, but I can't seem to get the basic `play()` method to work for Vimeo videos.

The example code from popcorn.js.org doesn't work for me. The video does not "play right away."

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

     var example = Popcorn.vimeo(
     '#video',
     'http://player.vimeo.com/video/25107077');

     // add a footnote at 2 seconds, and remove it at 6 seconds
     example.footnote({
       start: 2,
       end: 6,
       text: "Pop!",
       target: "footnotediv"
     });

     // play the video right away
     example.play();

  }, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `example.play()` into an appropriate listener. This should work:

```
example.listen( 'canplaythrough', function() {
  example.play();
});
```